# Should I delete my answer to a closed question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-delete

So I answered a [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/239838/what-should-i-watch-to-get-the-whole-star-wars-experience) and shortly after the question was closed because it was opinion-based. Should I remove my answer? I answered the question neatly and precisely, and I can't find anything wrong with my answer. But should I delete it anyway? I've even gotten votes to delete my answer and I'm wondering if it would be the best course of action to delete.

Comment: Generally up to you, the question _may_ end up reopened of course. It is preferable not to answer questions that should be closed but this was more of a grey area than others I admit. In any case if the situation stays as it is currently Roomba will delete the question, along with your answer, in just over a week.

Comment: I even edited my answer 3 times to make sure it was comprehensive, I kinda don't want to delete that if there's a chance of the question being reopened

Comment: I mean there’s always a chance it will be reopened. In this case though it seems to be either opinion based or a dupe so I wouldn’t hold your breath. FWIW I wouldn’t sweat too much about the vote to delete on your answer, some users just cast them on answers to closed questions no matter what.

Comment: "*I answered the question neatly and precisely, and I can't find anything wrong with my answer.*" - I downvoted it because I want to discourage people from answering questions that are clearly off-topic

Comment: The question wasn't off-topic. It was clearly a suggested order of question @Valorum

Comment: on a sci-fi movie franchise @Valorum

Comment: @Firestryke - No, it's not a suggested order. It's an opinion-based question asking people for the best order to get "the Star Wars experience". Hence why it was rapidly closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ordinarily, my advice would be to look through [these eleven questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstar-wars%5D+%5Bsuggested-order%5D+closed%3Ano+is%3Aquestion) to find one where your answer would be more appropriate, then go through all of the answers to that question, and make sure none of them are substantially identical to your answer. If you could find such a question, and your answer would contribute something new there, then it might be appropriate to re-post it there. If you could not find such a question, I might advise you to post a new one and self-answer it.

However, in this case, much of your answer is duplicative of [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112473/36526), which goes into significantly greater depth about *why* people recommend watching the films in numerical order rather than release order or some other order. There's also [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/225342/36526), which discusses the animated series in a fair amount of detail.

In short: Yes, I think you should delete your answer.

Comment: I couldn't really find a more appropriate question for my answer and no my answer isn't a duplicate of the first one you showed.